# Issue with CRMContainer in Twilio Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I built a simple plugin that shows in the CRMContainer the url of my CRM given some attributes parameters (if they are passed by), during inbound tasks this works fine, but the problem is that during outbound calls the behaviour is not the one expected, this is the piece of code:

```
flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uriCallback = (task) => {
  return task
 
    ? `https://mycrm.zzz/${task.attributes.clicar}/${task.attributes.contacth}/`
    : 'https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/';
  }
```

}

I would need an additional condition that tells the code, if this is an outbound voice call to always show a default url.
I tried adding an if/else that checks if task.attributes.direction is outbound, but Flex says this is undefined.
Any tip?
Thanks

Max

Comment: I just made an outbound call and logged the `task.attributes` from within the `uriCallback` and I found that there was `task.attributes.direction` set to `outbound`. Can you share the code that you are now using and the full error message?

Comment: Hi @philnash with the code above during an Outbound call the CRM panel gives back such url https://mycrm.zzz/undefined/undefined/

because such 2 attributes are only in inbound calls, and hence I get this error.
My goal is to have the code above working only during inbound, while during outbound would be ok for me not to do anything and leave the UL int he CRM panel as it is. 
I initially added an if/else checking the before the return task that checks task.attributes.direction but it didn't work (not defined).
Any tips?

Comment: Can you share the code you have? I’ll try it in my project and see what I can find.

Comment: The code is the one in the first post, whenever I try to add an if/else based on task.attributes.direction it gives error because task.attributes.direction is not defined.
the code is based on this quickstart: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin it's fine for inbound tasks, but there is an issue during outbound.
If there would be a way to limit the execution of the code int he plugin only fo inbound task that would be great

Comment: But that code doesn't include looking for `task.attributes.direction`? What is the code that is not working for you?

Comment: I attempted many, this is the last:

   flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uriCallback = (task) => {
      if (task.attributes.direction === 'outbound'){
      return task
     
        ? `https://mycrm.zzz/${task.attributes.clicar}/${task.attributes.contacth}/`
        : 'https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/';
     
    } else {
      return task
      ? `https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/`
        : 'https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/';
     
    }
  
  }


Flex doesn't open and when I download the error report the issue is: ""Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')"

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code, that's helped me understand what as gone wrong! Check out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't checking for the existence of the `task`. Your original code had this:

```js
flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uriCallback = (task) => {
  return task
    ? `https://mycrm.zzz/${task.attributes.clicar}/${task.attributes.contacth}/`
    : 'https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/';
  }
}
```

Which returns the URL with the task attributes in it only if the `task` exists, because of the ternary conditional.

So, when you try to use the attributes you need to make sure the `task` exists. So taking your code from the last comment, it should look like this:

```js
flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uriCallback = (task) => {
  if (task) {
    if (task.attributes.direction === 'outbound'){
      return `https://mycrm.zzz/${task.attributes.clicar}/${task.attributes.contacth}/`;
    } else {
      return `https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/`
    }
  } else {
    return 'https://mycrm.zzz/contacts/';
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad we got there in the end!